# When NULL is not a NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database I've imported from Access and there are a few columns displaying some unusual behavior. The particular columns are of type datetime, with NULL values allowed. The original dataset had some rows with dates, and some with null, and I'm trying to select all the rows with no dates (IS NULL) and always coming back with "Empty set". Please excuse the horrendous columns names, long story, and check out the abbreviated table with the three field PK and followed by the column in question:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                                   | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| HID                                     | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| yr                                      | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| mo                                      | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin     | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

Running a simple query against it pulls out the following:

```
mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" IS NOT NULL LIMIT 5;
+-----+------+----+-------------------------------------+
| hid | yr   | mo | wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin |
+-----+------+----+-------------------------------------+
| 109 | 2010 | 01 | NULL                                |
| 109 | 2011 | 03 | NULL                                |
| 109 | 2012 | 01 | 2011-11-11 00:00:00                 |
| 109 | 2012 | 02 | 2011-11-11 00:00:00                 |
| 109 | 2012 | 03 | NULL                                |
+-----+------+----+-------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" IS NULL LIMIT 5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Very strange behavior, so I am thinking that maybe it is somehow a string, thanks to a possibly faulty import, so I broke every rule in the book trying the following, and nothing would let me get the rows that were NULL separated from those with values.

```
mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" = "NULL" LIMIT 5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" = NULL LIMIT 5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" = 0 LIMIT 5;
+-----+------+----+-------------------------------------+
| hid | yr   | mo | wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin |
+-----+------+----+-------------------------------------+
| 109 | 2010 | 01 | NULL                                |
| 109 | 2011 | 03 | NULL                                |
| 109 | 2012 | 01 | 2011-11-11 00:00:00                 |
| 109 | 2012 | 02 | 2011-11-11 00:00:00                 |
| 109 | 2012 | 03 | NULL                                |
+-----+------+----+-------------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" = "" LIMIT 5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT hid, yr, mo, `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` FROM AP WHERE "wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin" = '' LIMIT 5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So I am a bit stumped. I've found numerous other stackoverflow articles on "How do I select for nulls" but none where "IS NOT NULL" so strangely returns rows with NULL in them (and IS NULL returns an Empty set every time).

Comment: +1 for nicely formatted code and giving all the required info

Comment: Quotes are for **values**, backticks are for column/table names etc. Your queries are literally saying find where `"this string" IS NULL` - which is never true.

Comment: Yup, Thanks Scrowler. I started to notice the behavior when I first put the column in the SELECT part, "SELECT HID, yr, mo, "Column X"" and it would return the string "Column X". Made me think it was a syntactical thing, and not the fault of my Access importer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with back ticks instead of double quotes in **where** clause because it's field name

```
SELECT hid,
       yr,
       mo,
       `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin`
FROM AP
WHERE `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` IS NULL LIMIT 5;
```

Actually below query will not check **where** condition for `NOT NULL` that's why it return all records change following query to back ticks instead of double quote like

```
SELECT hid,
       yr,
       mo,
       `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin`
FROM AP
WHERE `wanem deit yu yu risivim ol meresin` IS NOT NULL LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. You beat me to "Answering my own question" by a whole 3 minutes. Pesky things. Thanks for the help.